# Pass integer variable to task without losing the integer type

Tags: ansible

I've got a task (actually a role, but using a task here to make the example easier) that I don't own which does some operations on a variable. It assumes the variable is an integer. I need to somehow pass it a variable and have it come through as an int, and I'm not having any luck.

Here is a super simplified version of the task that I don't own:

**frob.yml**

```
- name: Validate that frob_count is <= 100
  fail: msg="{{frob_count}} is greater than 100"
  when: frob_count > 100

- name: Do real work
  debug: msg="We frobbed {{frob_count}} times!"
```

My playbook is:

```
- name: Frob some things
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    things:
      - parameter: 1
      - parameter: 2
      - parameter: 45
  tasks:
    - with_items: "{{things}}"
      include: frob.yml
      vars:
        frob_count: "{{item.parameter}}"
```

No matter what, I get errors like "1 is greater than 100" from `frob.yml`. Looks like it's getting the var as a string instead of an integer.

I've tried stuff like `frob_count: "{{item.parameter | int}}"` with no luck. If I could change `frob.yml` it'd be easy, but like I said, that's out of my control. Any thoughts?

This is on Ansible 2.6.4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Upgrade to Ansible 2.7 (currently available as the [`stable-2.7`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/stable-2.7) branch, [scheduled for GA on Oct. 4th, 2018](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/roadmap/ROADMAP_2_7.html#release-schedule)).
2. Add `jinja2_native=True` to the `[defaults]` section of the `ansible.cfg` (or set an environment variable `ANSIBLE_JINJA2_NATIVE=True`.
3. Leave your code as in the question (i.e., `frob_count: "{{item.parameter}}"`).

The result:

```
TASK [Do real work] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "We frobbed 1 times!"
}

TASK [Validate that frob_count is <= 100] ************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Do real work] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "We frobbed 2 times!"
}

TASK [Validate that frob_count is <= 100] ************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Do real work] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "We frobbed 45 times!"
}
```

---

**Explanation**

Currently any value returned by Jinja2 template is a string, so even if you used the `int` filter inside (as in `{{item.parameter | int}}`) the output is always rendered to a string by Ansible.

[Ansible 2.7 will use](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/32738) (with the above parameter) a feature of Jinja 2.10 called [Native Python Types](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/nativetypes/) and retain the data type.

Comment: Sounds like I'll have to hope my organization adopts 2.7 quickly, or make a PR to the troublesome script and cross my fingers. Ah well. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, this is a proper workaround for Ansible issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17992

Answer (score 0):

When you send the variable with that `include` task, it turns into **unicode** even forcing **int** on your playbook. So you need to use the **int** filter on frob.yml like this:

**frob.yml**

```
- name: Validate that frob_count is <= 100
  fail: msg="{{frob_count}} is greater than 100"
  when: frob_count|int > 100
```

Comment: Yeah, but in my scenario I can't edit the task. Furthermore, passing an int literal (like `frob_count: 5`) works just fine

Comment: Hm, based on https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9362 and https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/708 it sounds like this is a Jinja issue...

Comment: @KelsonSilva "*When you send the variable with that `include` task, it turns into unicode*" -- wrong. You can replace `include` with `debug: msg={{ frob_count | type_debug }}` and you'll see the type is Unicode. `include`/"*sending*" (whatever it means) is not the reason.　And OP clearly said they have no control over `frob.yml`.

Comment: @techraf I see... Thank you for that explanation, my understanding was wrong about that... I appreciate!

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution that seems to work and it doesn't require the `ANSIBLE_JINJA2_NATIVE=True` env variable

If instead of

```
initialDelaySeconds: "{{ _initialDelaySeconds }}"
```

you do

```
initialDelaySeconds: |
    {{ _initialDelaySeconds }}
```

you can omit the " in the jinja template and the value is not converted to string!